# Why does anConsole Applications Console.ForegroundColor change everything back to white instead just the remaining stuff?

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

I want to make a Snake Game in C#.

**Please dont delete my question, i googled it for 2 hours and there was no working solution.**

Thatfor i made a Method InitializeMatchField which generates a array MatchField which are just space keys( 1 per index).
Then i call the method GenerateInitialSnake which generates a yellow snake (5 characters long) at x25y5 to 29x5y made from #(HashTags)

Then i display a rectangle container of # with the matchfield and the yellow snake at position then i get an Console.ReadKey and after this i want to change the rest of the matchfield displayed back to white.

But what i get is that everything turns white, including the snake that needs to be yellow.

How can i fix this?
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

class SnakeGame
{
    public static int consoleHeight;
    public static int consoleWidth;
    public static int bufferHeight;
    public static int bufferWidth;
    public static String currentMatchFieldValue;
    public static ConsoleColor currentColor;
    public static String currentColorAsString;

public static int matchFieldHeight;
public static int matchFieldWidth;
public static String[,,] matchField;
private const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
public const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;
public const int SC_SIZE = 0xF000;



public static void InitializeMatchfield()
{
    if (Console.WindowHeight != 32 || Console.WindowWidth != 100)
    {
        Console.SetWindowSize(100, 32);
    }
    DisableResize();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    consoleHeight = Console.WindowHeight;
    consoleWidth = Console.WindowWidth;
    bufferHeight = Console.BufferHeight;
    bufferWidth = Console.BufferWidth;

    matchFieldHeight = (Console.WindowHeight - 2);
    matchFieldWidth = (Console.WindowWidth - 2);


    matchField = new String[matchFieldHeight, matchFieldWidth, 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < matchField.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matchField.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            ConsoleColor currentColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            //Save a random number form 1-10 into array.
            matchField[i, j, 0] = " ";
            matchField[i, j, 1] = Convert.ToString(currentColor);
        }
    }
}

public static void DisplayMatchField()
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    for (int h = 0; h < consoleWidth; h++)
    {
        Console.Write("#");
    }
    Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    for (int i = 0; i < matchField.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Console.Write("#");
        for (int j = 0; j < matchField.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            currentMatchFieldValue = matchField[i, j, 0];
            currentColorAsString = matchField[i, j, 1];
            currentColor = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), currentColorAsString, true);
            Console.Write(currentMatchFieldValue, currentColor);

        }
        Console.Write('#');
        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    for (int h = 0; h < consoleWidth; h++)
    {
        Console.Write('#');
    }
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
}

public static void DisableResize()
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition, int wFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    IntPtr handle = GetConsoleWindow();
    IntPtr sysMenu = GetSystemMenu(handle, false);
    if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_MAXIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
        DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_SIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
    }

}

public static void GenerateInitialSnake()
{
    int startPositionX = 24;
    int startPositionY = 5;
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        int newCursorPositionX = (startPositionX + i);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;

        currentColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(newCursorPositionX, startPositionY);
        matchField[5, newCursorPositionX, 0] = ("#");
        matchField[5, newCursorPositionX, 1] = Convert.ToString(currentColor);
        Console.WriteLine(matchField[5, newCursorPositionX, 0]);
        
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

}

/*public static void UseColor(ConsoleColor colorOfFontOutput)
{

    ConsoleColor[] colors = (ConsoleColor[])ConsoleColor.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor));
    Console.ForegroundColor = colorOfFontOutput;

}*/

static void Main()
{
    InitializeMatchfield();
    GenerateInitialSnake();
    DisplayMatchField();



}

}
```

When you run the code you can see that after you press a key the whole console changes back to white. How can i fix this?

Comment: GenerateInitialSnake() sets the foreground color to white.  Then  DisplayMatchField() executes a bunch of Console.Write() statements without setting the foreground color, so they appear white.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the snake you set the foreground colour to white, whereas in other places within the code you use the colour for each write, might be why.

I would suggest moving colouring into a method where you have to specify the colour and position, that way you're sure that you always give a colour that you're aware of, instead of leaving it on 'auto-pilot' if you forget etc.

Comment: Another suggestion might be to move the colour and position into their own type, to make it a bit less of an array excavation effort, and reduce conversion funny business

Comment: yes in the GenerateInitialSnake() at the end of the snake i set the color to white, but how else can i ensure the rest behind the snake is white?

Comment: when i dont set it to white at the end of GenerateInitialSnake() the whole border made of hashtags also turns yellow(DisplayMatchField is yellow)

Comment: the code as it is: before the readkey it displays only the snake in yellow. after the readkey it displays the snake and border in white